# Is there a general notion of orientability, e.g. for the rationals?

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question

I was discussing orientability with a friend today. To me, orientation is a subtle concept I hardly understand. To get my perspective across, I was trying to come up with spaces which are intuitively orientable, but hard to orientate mathematically, and vice versa.

In this line of thought, I was wondering if there is a such general notion of orientability which allows the rational line $ℚ \subseteq ℝ$ or the rational circle $ℚ^2 ∩ S^1$ to be come orientable?

---

Let me get more precise (as there has been some discussion). I’m interested in a definition of orientability

- (a) applicable to unusual, yet imaginable spaces like $ℚ$,
- (b) fitting well with the intuition for these spaces, and
- (c) generalising the usual notion for orientability for manifolds (if possible),

where I care less about (c) and more about (a) and (b). Alternatively, I would like to see an argument, based on intuition, for why such a notion isn’t sensible. I hope this isn’t too vague.

Comment: What would you want to orient the rational line or the rational circle for? In algebraic topology orienting a manifold gets you something, namely Poincare duality. What kind of Poincare duality could you hope to get for $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: (The only kind I can think of, which does not hold, is $H_0(\mathbb{Q}) \cong H^0(\mathbb{Q})$. These need to be interpreted appropriately; I'm taking the version of homology and cohomology which is invariant under weak equivalences, and $\mathbb{Q}$ is weak equivalent to $\mathbb{Q}$ with the discrete topology.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I was coming from a more intuitive view point, regarding an orientation of a line as a choice of “left” and “right”, which should be possible for the ratonal line as well. Perhaps my notion of orientation is too naïve?

Comment: I mean, you can think about whatever notions of orientation you want, but the practical question is whether you can do anything with them. What can you do with an orientation on $\mathbb{Q}$ that you can't do with an orientation on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I wouldn’t know, I don’t even care about the pragmatic use of such a notion. I was merely hoping for any sort of definition for orientability, (a) applicable to unusual, yet imaginable spaces like $ℚ$, (b) fitting well with the intuition for these spaces, and (c) generalising the usual notion for orientability for manifolds.

Comment: I'm not aware of such a notion.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Okay, thank you anyways.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I'd say that the rational projective plane is less orientable than ${\mathbb Q}^2$ is, and it should be possible to catch this fact using homogeneous coordinates.